# How to remove these lines in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I would be very glad if someone help me with this:

I have a list like this :

`44444444444:teste73`
`33333333333:254273`
`22222222222:7t2e2s`
`11111111111:111111`
`teste@yahoo.com:11111111111`
`teste@yahoo.com:22222222222`
`teste@yahoo.com:teste@yahoo.com`

I would like to remove lines with alphanumeric after : without removing the :

result must be like this:

`33333333333:254273`
`11111111111:111111`
`teste@yahoo.com:11111111111`
`teste@yahoo.com:22222222222`

All numeric text before : is not removed! only remove if numeric is after :

I tried something like this `[\u\l\s\.*::]` but didn't work well.

Thank you so much

Comment: Try `.*:(?!\d+$).*\R?`

Comment: "Alphanumeric" normally means letters or digits. Your example text shows removing lines with letters (i.e. `a` to `z`) after the colon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use menu => **Search** => **Mark**, select "Bookmark line", "Wrap around" and "Regular expression". Put `:.*[a-z]` into "Find what" and click "Mark all". Expect to see blue blobs at the left of all lines that should be deleted. Use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove bookmarked lines**.